# STL sort function with comparator

Tags: c++, stl

This is a syntax question.

[C++ STL sort function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/):

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

The documentation says that `comp` can be either a function pointer or an object.

But if you pass a function pointer, what mechanism of C++ allows the function pointer to be used in place of an object i.e. `Compare comp`?

Why isn't it a compile error?

Comment: _"what mechanism of C++ allows the function pointer to be used in place of an object i.e. Compare comp?"_ The call `operator()()`.

Comment: What is the syntax for calling a function using a pointer?  What is the syntax for calling a functor's `operator()`?  They're the same, that's why there is no compiler error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but they're still different types.

Comment: @Adrian: That's why `sort` is a function *template*. So it can work with different types.

Comment: @Adrian What is the purpose of a template?  Look closely at your example -- `Compare` is a template type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That's a bit colloquial. `operator()` is the name of a function, and calling through a function pointer doesn't involve a separate function call. Rather, it's a core expression in the language. The real point is that expressions in the language *can* resort to overload resolution to find certain functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie when you pass a function pointer, what does the type "Compare" resolve to?

Comment: @Adrian - Does it matter?  Within the body of the template, how is the call made?  That's the magic.  If you need convincing, write a non-template function that takes a function pointer, and inside that function, call the function.  You will see that the call is `ptr(arguments)`, assuming that `ptr` is the function pointer.  How does that differ if a functor was passed named `ptr`?  None.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought it does matter; I guess I don't fully understand how templates work. So what is the generated code if you pass a function pointer?

Comment: @Adrian Again, write a function that takes a function pointer and call that function.  Write another function that looks exactly like it, but passes a functor.  Compare the difference -- if written correctly, you will see that the only difference is the parameter type, which corresponds to the sample you posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get the syntax is same. What I don't get is the C++ template rules that allows this. `Compare comp` seems to indicate an object of type `Compare`; what allows you to pass a function pointer without using `std::ptr_fun` or some boost thing? That's the question.

Comment: @Adrian Why do you think you need to do anything special?  `int(*)()` is the type that means a pointer to a function that returns an int and takes no arguments.  That whole thing is `Compare`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an object with a function call operator,

```
struct Functor {

  bool operator()(const Foo& a, const Foo& b) {
    return a < b;
  }

};
```

it is easy to see that the `sort` function can be instantiated such that the `Compare comp` parameter accepts a `Functor` object.

```
sort(/* other params we don't care about here */, Functor comp);
```

Fair enough.

Your question is - how can this accept a function pointer? Let's begin by examining what is the type of a function pointer?

Consider the following

```
bool compare(const Foo& a, const Foo& b);
bool (*func_ptr)(const Foo&, const Foo&) = compare;
```

The type of a pointer to the function `compare`, as shown in the second line above, is `bool (*)(const Foo&, const Foo&)`. You can typedef this just as you can any other type:

```
typedef bool (*func_ptr_type)(const Foo&, const Foo&);
func_ptr_type ptr = compare;
```

Or equivalently:

```
using func_ptr_type = bool(*)(const Foo&, const Foo&);
func_ptr_type ptr = compare;
```

Now, when you provide a function pointer to `std::sort`, it should be obvious that the type  `Compare` becomes the pointer type, analogous to `func_ptr_type` above, and the argument looks much the same as the example in the second line:

```
sort(/* other params we don't care about here */, func_ptr_type comp);
```

This all works because the `sort` function is actually a function template. It gets instantiated with different types based on its usage. When it's instantiated with an object, its parameter accepts that object by value (the `Compare` type is deduced to be the type of the object). When it's instantiated with a function pointer, the `Compare` type is deduced to be the function pointer type.